# Pass "git parameters" from pipeline jenkins job A to job B

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline jenkins job A and a jenkins job B, which might or might not be a pipeline job.
I have to:

- Step 1). Trigger job B from job A and
- Step 2). Pass **git    parameters** ( branch name and credentials )
  from job A to job B, so    that a project is checked out when job B
  is triggered into the workspace of job B.

For now, i'm able to trigger job B from job A, I am not able to achieve step 2.
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: If job a is a pipeline you can use the pipeline syntax generator. Just select "build" and just enter some values for each parameter, that add it to your pipeline and replace those values with the right variables

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it.

### Jenkins file

pass variables between pipeline if using a file.
You mentioned you are not using pipeline so I assume you are not working with JenkinsFile

```
pipeline {
    // Define the desired paramaters
    parameters {
        string(name: 'var1', defaultValue: '')
        }

        // Define global variable
        stage("define global var") {
             steps {
               env.var1 = value1
              }
        }
     
        stage("test variables") {
            steps {
              echo "${env.var1}"
            }
        }
  }
```

### Write the variables to file

Write the variables to file and then read it from the disk.

### Adding a set variable step

```
// First set the variables

script
{
    env.var1_name = "var1_value"
    .....
    env.varX_name = "varX1_value"

    // Print the values of the variables
    echo " My vars[DEV:${env.var1_name }] 
}
```

- Full script will look like

```
stage('define glbal variables') {
    script
    {
        env.var1_name = "var1_value"
        .....
        env.varX_name = "varX1_value"

        // Print the values of the variables
        echo " My vars[DEV:${env.var1_name }] 
    }
}

// Define Job which need teh value of the variable
stage('Job A') {
    echo "NEXT JOB DEV version = ${env.var1_name }"
}

stage('Job B') {
    echo "NEXT JOB DEV version = ${env.var1_name }"
}
```

### Define a global variable

```
// Define a ---groovy--- global named [var1] which can be shared between steps
var1 = 'value1'

...

pipeline {
  stages {
    stage('A') {
      steps {
        echo "${var1}" 
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I am using pipeline script in job A, since job A is a pipeline job, and how do I insure that once job A triggers job B, the project from git will be checked out in the workspace of job B ?